# Use parts of WinRT by PInvoke

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime

I tried to use some WinRT functions in my C# Application (A normal Windows Programm not a Universal App), the normal way does not work in my case. Like discribed on: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/457335/How-to-call-WinRT-APIs-from-NET-desktop-apps

So I think about calling the WinRT API by P/Invoke. I found a lot of questions about the other way (Use P/Invore in WinRT).

So my questions does anyone know a way to call WinRt functions by P/Invoke?

Thanks,
Daniel

-- Edit --

To Compleate my question this is the Code thaht does not work:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
        {

                // Check Microsoft Passport is setup and available on this machine
                if (await MicrosoftPassportHelper.MicrosoftPassportAvailableCheckAsync())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Microsoft Passport is setup!");
                }
                else
                {
                    // Microsoft Passport is not setup so inform the user
                    Console.WriteLine(("Microsoft Passport is not setup!\r\n" +
                                          "Please go to Windows Settings and set up a PIN to use it.");
                }

        });

public static async Task<bool> MicrosoftPassportAvailableCheckAsync()
        {
            var keyCredentialAvailable = KeyCredentialManager.IsSupportedAsync();
            if (keyCredentialAvailable.GetResults() == false)
            {
                // Key credential is not enabled yet as user 
                // needs to connect to a Microsoft Account and select a PIN in the connecting flow.
                Debug.WriteLine("Microsoft Passport is not setup!\nPlease go to Windows Settings and set up a PIN to use it.");
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
```

I get a ArgumentException from the Line "if (keyCredentialAvailable.GetResults() == false)".

Value does not fall within the expected range.
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
    at PassportTest.MicrosoftPassportHelper.d__0.MoveNext()

As fare as I found out this is because the KeyCredentialManager is not supportet outside from Universial Apps. That is why I want to check is p/invoke may an Option.

Comment: The winrt api is COM under the hood.  You never use pinvoke to call COM interfaces.  Nor can you, these methods are not exported but are bound at runtime.   It just isn't necessary, it just takes some hanky-panky with the project file to convince Visual Studio that it should let you call winrt api methods from a non-winrt app.

Comment: The part of WinRT I need to use is not on compatibililist (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn554295%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and do not work with that hanky-panky in project files.

Comment: That list is only relevant to winapi functions.  Sure, not all hanky-panky can work, not naming the winrt interface you are trying to use makes it very difficult to get a useful answer of course.

Comment: I try to use "KeyCredentialManager.IsSupportedAsync()" in my application, but it fails with an ArgumentException.Error Value does not fall within the expected range.
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()

Comment: It belongs in your question, not a comment.  With a snippet so other SO users can reproduce the problem.